# Matplotlib legend for an arrow

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to know how it is possible to label an `arrow` and show it in the legend of a plot.

For instance if I do this

```
 arrow(0,1,'dummy',label='My label')

 legend()
```

I do not see anything in the legend. I would like to see in the legend box an arrow next to its label.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add arbitrary artists to the legend command, as explained [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html)

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = plt.figure()
arrow = plt.arrow(0, 0, 0.5, 0.6, 'dummy',label='My label')
plt.legend([arrow,], ['My label',])
```

The arrow artist does not allow a marker parameter, so you'll need to do some additional manual tinkering to replace the marker in the legend.

**EDIT**

To get the custom marker you need to define your own `handler_map`. The following code is inspired in the example [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/legend_demo_custom_handler.html?highlight=legend_handlers):

```python
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerPatch
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

def make_legend_arrow(legend, orig_handle,
                      xdescent, ydescent,
                      width, height, fontsize):
    p = mpatches.FancyArrow(0, 0.5*height, width, 0, length_includes_head=True, head_width=0.75*height )
    return p

f = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
arrow = plt.arrow(0,0, 0.5, 0.6, 'dummy', label='My label', )
plt.legend([arrow], ['My label'], handler_map={mpatches.FancyArrow : HandlerPatch(patch_func=make_legend_arrow),
                    })
```

Comment: thank you, but this only partly answer to my question. The thing is that I would like to have an arrow as the marker.

Comment: That's cool. How to annotate both an up and down arrow in the legend?

Comment: Alternatively, is it possible to get the label from `legend` or `orig_handle` in the arguments passed to the function? I checked `.get_lablel()`, but it returns empty string, why?

Comment: In this example, some FacyArrow arguments don't seem to have an effect, such as fc, ec, alpha: the arrow is always show in in default color. Why is that?

Answer (score 9):

You can add any latex symbol as a marker.
For example: for an arrow pointing down you can specify:

```
scatter( x ,y, c='purple',marker=r'$\downarrow$',s=20, label='arrow' )
```