# add label to legend for matplotlib annotation

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am "annotating" many arrows of a certain color to add data to the graph (where events occurred). ([example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34017866/arrow-on-a-line-plot-with-matplotlib)). Is there a way to add it to the legend? One answer might be to add them [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500265/manually-add-legend-items-python-matplotlib) as I show in the code below, but I guess it is always the last resort. What is the "right" way to do it? (bonus for also having a small arrow mark in the legend)

Here is an example, but really, the example is for ease of use, the question is just how to add label for `line.axes.annotate`

Here is a code which is almost identical to the one in the link:
A function to add arrows to

```
def add_arrow(line, position=None, direction='right', size=15, color=None, length=None):
    """
    add an arrow to a line.

    line:       Line2D object
    position:   x-position of the arrow. If None, mean of xdata is taken
    direction:  'left' or 'right'
    size:       size of the arrow in fontsize points
    color:      if None, line color is taken.
    length:     the number of points in the graph the arrow will consider, leave None for automatic choice
    """
    if color is None:
        color = line.get_color()

    xdata = line.get_xdata()
    ydata = line.get_ydata()

    if not length:
        length = max(1, len(xdata) // 1500)
    if position is None:
        position = xdata.mean()
    # find closest index
    start_ind = np.argmin(np.absolute(xdata - position))
    if direction == 'right':
        end_ind = start_ind + length
    else:
        end_ind = start_ind - length
    if end_ind == len(xdata):
        print("skipped arrow, arrow should appear after the line")
    else:
        line.axes.annotate('',
                           xytext=(xdata[start_ind], ydata[start_ind]),
                           xy=(xdata[end_ind], ydata[end_ind]),
                           arrowprops=dict(
                               arrowstyle="Fancy,head_width=" + str(size / 150), color=color),
                           size=size
                           )
```

A function that uses it

```
def add_arrows(line, xs, direction='right', size=15, color=None, name=None):
    if name:
        if color is None:
            color = line.get_color()
        patch = mpatches.Patch(color=color, label=name, marker="->")
        plt.legend(handles=[patch])
    for x in xs:
        add_arrow(line, x, color=color)
```

An example to what line is

```
x,y = [i for i in range(10000)], [i for i in range(10000)] 
line = plt.plot(x, y, label="class days")[0]
add_arrows(line, (x,y))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please include relevant code in question.

Comment: @Julien added, thanks for the help

Comment: Might be good to also explain why you are not happy with your current code... Current figure vs desired result...

Comment: As I wrote, I have the desired result (well i'll be happy for a small arrow in the legened but that is not the reason for the question), it is a question of writing good code. I am using a manual walkaround.

Comment: ok but then add that result here so we can have an idea of what you want to achieve in one glance rather than guessing by reading your code...

Comment: indeed, the code in the question does not show how `add_arrows` is used. So even if someone wanted to dive into this and actually run to code to get an idea of the desired output, they wouldn't know which arguments to put into `add_arrows`.